# Installing an aftermaret cd player Peugeot 307 2003

Tags: audio

I want to install Halfords | Pioneer DEH-1700UB Car Stereo

to my 307 , 2003 model.

I managed to takeout the factory fitted player.
Do I need additional adapters or kit to install this ?

Answer (score 1):

Generically, in almost every aftermarket head unit install, you'll need two adapters to make it look and work correctly *easily*.

First, you'll need an adapter which functions as a face plate. This provides coverage for areas which the stereo itself does not cover.

Second, You'll need an adapter to more easily get the wiring from the head unit to work with the wiring in the car. In a lot of cases, you don't *need* this. You can hack the wiring in the car into oblivion and directly attach the head unit wiring into it. Two reasons why you wouldn't want to do this: 1) getting the adapter is much easier, faster, efficient; 2) if you ever want to put the stock unit back in, you've made a huge mess out of wiring harness, so would be a huge pain in the butt.

Get the adapter kits. They are usually relatively painless to the pocket book, especially if you want the installation to look its best and for the head unit to easily function correctly. Saves a lot of headaches.